# MATLAB Wavelet Transform - reproducing toolkit settings

Tags: matlab, filter, transform, signal-processing, wavelet

FYI: This is a question I posted on the MATLAB answers site, but am not getting any real feedback or views, so I am reposting on Stack Overflow ([Matlab Answers Link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/328617-using-a-specific-wavelet-transform-on-new-ecg-signals)).

I'm working with ECG signals and am trying to use a wavelet technique to reduce some of the noise in various data sets. I was able to use a 'Continuous Wavelet 1-D using FFT' technique in the Wavelet Analyzer toolkit to achieve a good response (at least on one sample). I have exported the CWTFT struct to a variable called CWTS and want to apply the same wavelet function on a number of other pieces of data.

How I generated the wavelet transformed data: 1-D/FFT -> 'dog', 6 parameter, linear analysis, linear synthesis, scale limited to first 16 options

The CWTS file exported from the tool kit contains the following fields: CWTS.cfs, CWTS.scales, CWTS.frequencies, CWTS.omega, CWTS.meanSIG, CWTS.dt, CWTS.wav

How can I apply the same transformation to new data via the matlab command window?  I assume the exported CWTS information should be able to inform a function that I can apply on new data.  The only way I can reproduce it currently is to open up a new data set in the toolkit and select all the options again.

Here are the pre / post transform plots of the data:

Pre-Transform/Raw Data

[image]

Post-Transform

[image]

Comment: It is unclear, what are you asking about exactly? Do you want a noise removal technique based on wavelets? Want to know which wavelet dictionary is the most suitable? Have problem in coding the procedure? what?

Comment: Thanks MimSaad.  Sorry for not being more explicit.  I have revised the above question.   Essentially I am able to get a good wavelet transform via toolkit and export the settings that worked, but am unable to find the function that would execute the same transform on new data without having to open the toolkit/toolbox again.  I assume this is possible within matlab, but did not find documentation to help me use the exported CWTS data.

Comment: So, I think giving out your parameters and setting of wavelet, and asking for how implementing it in form of matlab code would help more.